# What model tells us there is nothing outside the universe?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, big-bang, topology

Is there an existing model or theory that shows there is nothing outside of the universe that interacts with anything inside the universe?  Or to put it in other words, is there a model or theory showing that everything happening inside the universe including the expansion of the universe itself is caused by forces and masses inside the universe?  Obviously dark energy is the big question here.  I'm not promoting that there is something, I'm just asking to be pointed to an existing model, study or theory.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, the answer depends on how you define the universe. In one sense, there can be nothing outside of the universe because the universe is, by definition, everything that exists, has ever existed, or will ever exist.

However, "universe" is sometimes used as a shorthand for the [observable universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe) - that part of the universe that we can observe (in theory) right now. The observable universe is finite because of the finite speed of light. We can be almost certain that the observable universe is not the whole universe, so that there are probably galaxies that are outside of the observable universe. These galaxies can interact with galaxies that are currently inside the observable universe. However, these interactions cannot spread faster than the speed of light, so by the time we are able to observe such an interaction, the galaxy that was outside of the observable universe will now be within the observable universe.

In other words, we cannot ever observe any effects that originate from outside of the observable universe because (as far as we know) no such effects can propagate at a speed that is faster than light.

There are theories such as [string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) that require additional dimensions of space beyond the three dimensions that we are familiar with. Things happening in these extra dimensions can affect things that we can see in our three macroscopic dimensions. But I don't think any physicist would say that these extra dimensions (if they exist) are *outside* of our universe. They are certainly not outside of spacetime - they just mean that spacetime has to be expanded (somehow - but exactly how we don't yet know) to include these extra dimensions.

Comment: I am not thinking about distant galaxies or anything else within our universe, even our observable universe.  I'm asking if everything that goes on within our universe is explainable from within, or if there is any influence from outside.  And I'm not looking for a definitive answer, just want to know if this has been studied.

Comment: @foolishmuse Yes, this has been studied in cosmology. Nothing outside of the observable universe can have affected anything inside the observable universe *at the time at which we see it*, because the observable universe is expanding at the speed of light. You must remember that most of the observable universe is a long distance away, and so we are not seeing it as it is "now" but as it was millions or even billions of years ago.

Comment: @foolishmuse I have expanded my answer to address some wider issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I am not asking if there is something outside the universe.  I am asking if there is a model or theory showing that nothing from outside the universe interacts with anything inside the universe?  I want to start research into this concept so I'm looking for existing studies on it.

Comment: @foolishmuse You don't need a model or theory, you just need the definition of universe - everything that exists, has ever existed, or will ever exist. Using this definition, nothing outside of the universe can interact with anything inside the universe because logically anything that interacts with other things in the universe is itself in the universe. I am talking here in the context of mainstream science of course, not religion, philosophy or fringe science.

Answer (score 1):

Term "outside" assumes that spacetime extends far beyond universe, which is false. If there's "outside" then by definition it's part of universe. Imagine your question absurdity if you would be in the last room of current floor and would still ask "What's in the next **room** on the same floor? " No room = No "outside" in universe. Everything is inside.

To some degree, you can imagine that universe reassembles [Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_(1997_film)) structure of inter-connected rooms (depicted in 1997 film), when seemingly reached "last room to be" leads just to another room or to the first room where everybody has been before. So, like no way to get out of the cube for the movie protagonists, there's no way to get "out of universe". It's beauty and The Curse at the same time. HTH !

Comment: I was thinking of what is beyond the spacetime of our own universe.   Is there any influence from beyond spacetime to inside the universe?  What I am looking for is a study or theory that offers some evidence  (or lack of evidence if necessary) of just what you are saying.

Comment: Again, term "beyond" assumes sort of extension of our space further from universe, which is illegal to imagine. By asking "beyond", "outside", etc, it's like you would imagine some observer from "beyond" which could look into our universe, and say,- "Hey I see you !". But if so, then this observer and our universe must be connected by some causal/space-time relations and so it proves that term "outside" is incompatible with term "universe". But I understand that your neighbor next door can live in "other universe outside" :-D

Comment: If we define our universe as what is inside of spacetime,  I'm thinking of outside of spacetime.  And again, I'm not looking for a definitive answer here, just looking for models or studies that I can look at.

Comment: Universe is not "something inside spacetime", but rather it is spacetime itself. Anyway, I have put my reasoning in the post and comments, if it still feels like you would want to go "outside", then I can't help you, but cry :-( And yes, I'm highly skeptical about multiverse theories,- we have issues about universe exploration, let alone _observable universe_ exploration. So multiverse theories introduces such level of complexity, which is on par with string theories complexity. They may look nice, but IMO, the more science will go to such direction, the less scientific it will be.

Comment: I should explain what I mean by "less scientific method". By definition all scientific theories are validated by experiments/observations. The more harder for validation theory is,- the farther it is from falsifiable part of theories and closer to unfalsifiable theories part in theories spectrum, which are based solely on pure belief and hence,- unscientific. Surely as technology and science advances, time-to-validation increases. That's understandable, but... at one point it may become too hard to distinguish this complexity phenomena from simply "pure belief systems" hidden under math cover.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I am not asking if there is something outside the universe.  I am asking if there is a model or theory showing that nothing from outside the universe interacts with anything inside the universe?  I want to start research into this concept so I'm looking for existing studies on it.   So I guess I could ask, where did you get the information on which you based your answers?

Comment: Sure you are not asking, but assuming instead that there can be something outside the universe, while it can't. How I base that ? I explained to you, it's just common sense and logics.